# Is it possible to define multi line headlines in custom table styles?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to create a table that has more than only 1 line as a headline (thus 2-3 lines as I've got topics and subtopics in the columns).

Is it possible to define these multi line headlines in custom table styles for word?

Comment: custom table style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the lines you want to define as heading line, then in the layout menu hit the "repeat heading lines" button.

[image]

The selected lines will all be defined as heading lines and behave the same way the first one did.

Comment: One point to add here (as I just managed to try it out at long last): If you also use an autostyle you need to set the autostyle first and then do as told in this answer.